# Access to a server behind the SonicWall from the LAN using Public IP addresses

Tags: firewall, lan, sonicwall, wan

We have a SonicWall TZ 400 with a Comcast Modem in Bridge Mode. Everything works fine, except the fact that the exposed services on the LAN couldn´t be reached using the public IP of the WAN from the LAN zone.

We tried these steps with NAT Policies but doesn´t work.

https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505780814635

This is the NAT policy configured only for test the access of the dot200 Services:

[image: NAT Policy]

These are the firewall rules WAN-LAN:

[image]

This is the only LAN-WAN rule configured:

[image]

Monitoring the packets we have this log:

```
*Packet number: 1220*
Header Values:
 Bytes captured: 62, Actual Bytes on the wire: 62
Packet Info(Time:01/25/2019 12:53:49.112):
 in:X0*(interface), out:--, DROPPED, Drop Code: 717(Packet dropped - Policy drop), Module Id: 27(policy), (Ref.Id: _2118_qpmjdzDifdl), 2:1)
Ethernet Header
 Ether Type: IP(0x800), Src=[b8:ca:3a:9a:83:69], Dst=[xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]
IP Packet Header
 IP Type: TCP(0x6), Src=[10.1.10.6], Dst=[xx.xx.xx.xx]
TCP Packet Header
 TCP Flags = [SYN,], Src=[61006], Dst=[81], Checksum=0x7bd7
Application Header
 Not Known
```

What we done wrong?

Comment: Not only do you need to forward port through NAT, but you are going to need to create firewall rules to allow traffic originated from outside to inside. Firewalls default to blocking all outside originated traffic.

Comment: You should consider using split-brain DNS so you can bypass the firewall from LAN.

Comment: Hi @Ron, thanks. We have configured a firewall rules for the access of the WAN to the LAN, I attached the firewall rules on the original post.

Comment: Then, please attach any logs or debugs about what is happening.

Comment: This applicance have a lot of logs options, eg: Events log, Connection logs, Appflow logs, ... What we can use to detect the routing problem?

Comment: It may not be a routing problem (probably not a routing problem). It is probably a firewall problem. Also, what are the first two octets of the WAN address on the Sonicwall?

Comment: @Ron, looks like the packets are dropped. I started a monitor session and request a service of port 81 (TCP) using the WAN IP to avoid the DNS and the log is attached on the question

Comment: What is the WAN interface (X1?)?

Comment: @Zac67, first of all, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. But honestly, I'm a newbie in network issues. This split-brain DNS thought seems very complicated to me. Do we have another possible solution?

Comment: The X1 interface is for WAN and X0 for LAN.

Comment: Your log is showing a packet sourced from the inside (LAN to WAN), but your firewall rules are for packets sourced from the outside (WAN to LAN).

Comment: If you are doing LAN-to-LAN traffic, then your traffic will not pass through the firewall because it should never be routed. Your firewall rules and NAT are for traffic from the outside to the inside, not inside to inside. Traffic on the inside to the inside should use inside addressing, not the outside addressing.

Comment: Basically the traffic is LAN-LAN the only fact is we want to use the public IP of the WAN to access the services. We have only one firewall rule LAN-WAN. This line of the log, Dst=[98.xx.xx.xx] is the public IP, if I try to access with the service private IP 10.1.10.200 everything works.

Comment: "_Basically the traffic is LAN-LAN the only fact is we want to use the public IP of the WAN to access the services._ No, you don't. That causes suboptimal routing and places an unnecessary burden on your firewall. You want your internal DNS to translate to the internal services addresses. You can ask about that on [sf]. If you insist on doing it the way you are trying, then understand that is a rookie mistake, and you need to search for hairpin routing.

Comment: @Ron, then I have to add an internal DNS on the appliance configuration? You are right, this way put unnecessary burden on the firewall. I admit that I am a newbie, thank you very much for show me the way.

Comment: @Joseph "Split-brain DNS" is pretty simple, it just requires you to run some kind of DNS service (off-topic here). On that, you enter an A record for e.g. www.example.com -> 192.168.0.10 and that's it.

Comment: Then for example, I can use the DNS service of Windows Server machine on the network and add it as internal DNS on the appliance. The problem is if this server become shutdown.

Comment: A professionally managed network in a business environment (what is on-topic here) should have its own DNS server. At the very least, you want even your non-publicly exposed devices to be able to be resolved with DNS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is hairpin routing. This is not a good idea because it is suboptimal routing, involving NAT (a kludge that should be avoided whenever possible), and it unnecessarily burdens your firewall and slows your communication.

If you really want to do it, there are documents describing how. For example, [this one](https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505780814635):

> ### Configuring access to a server behind the SonicWall from the LAN / DMZ using Public IP addresses
>
> *Last Updated: 12/6/2018 **35339** Views **101** Users found this article helpful*
>
> ### Description
>
> This document describes how a host on a SonicWall LAN or DMZ can
>   access a server on the SonicWall LAN or DMZ using the server's public
>   IP address or FQDN.
>
> This document describes how a host on a SonicWall LAN can access a
>   server on the SonicWall LAN using the server's public IP address
>   (typically provided by DNS). Imagine a NSA 4500 (SonicOS Enhanced)
>   network in which the Primary LAN Subnet is 10.100.0.0 /24 and the
>   Primary WAN IP is 3.3.2.1. Let's say you have a Web site for your
>   customers, and its hostname is . You have already written the policies
>   and rules needed so that outsiders can get to the web site, but it's
>   really running on a private side server 10.100.0.2. Now imagine that
>   you are a person using a laptop on the private side, with IP of
>   10.100.0.200. You want to reach the server using its public name, because you do the same thing when your laptop is with you on the
>   road. If you sit on the private side, and request
>   http://www.domain.com>, loopback is what makes it possible for that to
>   work, even though the server is actually right next to you on a local
>   IP address.
>
> To allow this functionality you need to create a loop-back policy.
>
> ### Resolution
>
> The idea behind this policy is that you must translate your source
>   into a public object if you wish to talk to the public IPs from the
>   LAN.
>
> - Login to the SonicWall Management GUI.
> - Navigate to Manage | Policies | Rules | NAT Policies submenu.
> - Click on the Add button.
> - Create the following NAT Policy.
> - Original Source: LAN Subnets (or Firewalled Subnets if you want hosts    in other zones to be included)
> - Translated Source: WAN Interface IP
> - Original Destination: WAN Interface IP
> - Translated Destination: (LAN server object)
> - Original Service: Any
> - Translated Service: Original
> - Inbound Interface: Any
> - Outbound Interface: Any
>
> [image]

Comment: Definitely, hairpin routing is not the best choice. I like to do things right from the start.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer because it answered the original question so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. You can then ask about setting up DNS on [sf]. Unfortunately, server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.